# Changing a span in javascript with several different element IDs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to this and don't really know how to ask the question. Forgive me if it's not clear at the outset, but I'll present my code to explain it to you.

On my page I have a drop-down list that displays (a `<selector>` that has the ID : list-category)

I also have search results that pop up. And at the bottom of his results I would like to display what is selected in the `<selector>`. For info the `get_the_id()` function is given by the CMS (WordPress) to display the right image, or the right title. I simply assumed that in order for it to display my text several times, I had to rely on that too.

```
<div class="listing-cat">
        
        
        <i class="<?php echo $cat_icon; ?>"></i>
        <span id="<?php echo get_the_ID()?>"></span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function update() {
                var select = document.getElementById('list-category');
                var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

                document.getElementById('<?php echo get_the_ID()?>').innerHTML = option.text;
              
            }            
            update();
         </script>    
      </div>
```

After several tests I noticed that I only had the selected category displayed for the first search result and not for the others. I thought about it for a while and I said to myself, I'll use the unique ID of the post so that it will be correctly set up (reason why we see this PHP code)

Now nothing is displayed, but if I go into the source code of the web page, I can see that my PHP variables have the right ID of the post, I do not understand why it does not work:

```
<div class="listing-cat">
                
        <i class=""></i>
        <span id="69678"></span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function update() {
                var select = document.getElementById('list-category');
                var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

                document.getElementById('69678').innerHTML = option.text;
              
            }            
            update();
         </script>

      </div>
```

Do you have any leads to help me see what I might have missed? Do I need to make a loop?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change the text inside the `<span>` whenever the user changes the selected option in the `<select>` element?

Comment: The combination of PHP and JS together is strongly discouraged. Outside of that, we need your data from the backend (PHP) to give you the best answer. You gave a lot of information which is good for a first question! However, always remember to focus on your problem.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes, that's right, that's what I try to do with my code

Comment: @Wimanicesir Thanks for your reply. Sorry I wasn't aware that this was not recommended. I did however add some clarification to my question. Is there anything in particular that is not clear to you?

Comment: Alright! Out of curiosity, why are you using the ID of the post as the ID of the span? Are you writing this in a post loop or is there another specific reason? Could you also include the HTML of your `<select>` element?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier To be honest, I don't even know why I put this up. I looked at how the CMS built the blocks to have the title, image and description each time and it always adds a post ID. That's why I thought I should put this way. Because the first time, I set my ```<span>``` with as id "text" and this worked correctly, but only displayed the value once. Probably because on the page there was several times a ```<span id="text">``` I think, but not sure.

Comment: I see. You can use `get_the_ID()` to identify the current post you're on to or to get specific data (title, content, thumbnail) based on value of the ID. Are you saying that there are multiple `<span>` elements with the same ID on the page? Because your question does not reflect that. Though it is not the culprit of your issue.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier On my first try yes, but later on I included my PHP code to make each span unique.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Ok don't judge me but I found the problem. Elsewhere on the page, outside of this php file, there was already a ```<span id="post-id">``` and I made the change in my code so that now there is ```<span id="cat-postid">``` and it works perfectly.

Comment: No worries, glad you worked it out. Just make sure you delete the post.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is an *event-driven* language. That means that when something happens, like a user selects an option in a `<select>`, an event is fired. We can *listen* for events to do something whenever they happen.

In this case, the user will *change* the selected option in the `<select>` element. Therefor we can listen for the `change` event

Every HTML Element has a method called [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). With it we add a listener for a specific event that happens on that element and attach a function with what should happen whenever the event occurs.

With every event you get an [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) with information about the event, the element that triggered it, and more. The `target` property of the `Event` object is a reference to the element that triggered the event, in this case our `<select>` element.

The selected `value` of the selected option is reflected in the `value` property on the `<select>` element itself. Read it and set your text of your span to the value of the select.

```js
const listCategory = document.querySelector('#list-category');
const selectedCategory = document.querySelector('#selected-category');

listCategory.addEventListener('change', event => {
  selectedCategory.textContent = event.target.value;
});
```

```html
<select id="list-category">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<div class="listing-cat">
  <i class=""></i>
  <span id="selected-category">A</span>
</div>
```